# Eclipse generate many JFormattedTextField

Tags: user-interface, jframe, windowbuilder, jformattedtextfield, jform-designer

I implemented Gauss Jordan Algorithm in eclipse and now I am trying to make it be a software, however I have no experience at all with GUI.

I have a window that asks for input of 2 things number of variables and number of equations and when user enters the numbers and presses submit button, second window opens.

In that second window I need certain number of textfields to appear itself, which will be dependent on the two variables mentioned above.

My question is there any way to grab the value from first class(first window where user entered variables which I stores in first class) pass it to second one(second window where the textfields will appear) to tell it how many rows and columns should be generated with textfields and then the program would generate it?

I tried looking up on youtube, because I do not understand documentations well, so any answer would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the MVC pattern could help you to do this, check something like this:

http://www.austintek.com/mvc/